# sed command seems unfinished

Tags: shell, sed, centos7

I'm trying to replace an exact string but my sed command is returning an error. Looks like my comand isn't closed propery

```
sed -i s/\<"rpc-whitelist-enabled">/\<"rpc-whitelist-enabled" : false,\>/g somefile
```

**somefile**

```
"rpc-whitelist": "127.0.0.1",
"rpc-whitelist-enabled": true,
```

**Error**

[image: error]

**EDIT:**

This command won't change the value `true` into `false`

```
cat file-name | sed  s/"rpc-whitelist-enabled: true"/"rpc-whitelist-enabled : false"/g
```

Content of somefile :

```
{
    "alt-speed-down": 50,
    "alt-speed-enabled": false,
    "cache-size-mb": 4,
    "rpc-authentication-required": false,
    "rpc-bind-address": "0.0.0.0",
    "rpc-enabled": true,
    "rpc-host-whitelist": "",
    "rpc-host-whitelist-enabled": true,
    "rpc-username": "",
    "rpc-whitelist": "127.0.0.1",
    "rpc-whitelist-enabled": true,
    "scrape-paused-torrents-enabled": true,
    "script-torrent-done-enabled": false,
    "script-torrent-done-filename": "",
    "seed-queue-enabled": false,
    "start-added-torrents": true,
}
```

Comment: Try wrapping the `s` command with single quotes. `sed -i 's/<"rpc-whitelist-enabled">/<"rpc-whitelist-enabled" : false,>/g' somefile`

Comment: I don't know why, but it doesn't change the value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: The edit is solved the same way: `sed -i  's/"rpc-whitelist-enabled": true/"rpc-whitelist-enabled": false/g' file`

Comment: Doesn't work for the real content, sorry

Comment: Maybe because there is no `"` after `true`. It is a typo then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more issues with Your sed, rather use this one:

```
sed -i '/"rpc-whitelist-enabled": true,/s/true/false/' somefile
```

Test:

```
$ cat somefile | sed '/"rpc-whitelist-enabled": true,/s/true/false/'
{
    "alt-speed-down": 50,
    "alt-speed-enabled": false,
    "cache-size-mb": 4,
    "rpc-authentication-required": false,
    "rpc-bind-address": "0.0.0.0",
    "rpc-enabled": true,
    "rpc-host-whitelist": "",
    "rpc-host-whitelist-enabled": true,
    "rpc-username": "",
    "rpc-whitelist": "127.0.0.1",
    "rpc-whitelist-enabled": false,
    "scrape-paused-torrents-enabled": true,
    "script-torrent-done-enabled": false,
    "script-torrent-done-filename": "",
    "seed-queue-enabled": false,
    "start-added-torrents": true,
}
```

Comment: In Your provided somefile it does check the test, or provide exact content of Your file

Comment: Added in the question

Comment: Perfect ! Working great

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understood exactly but tried with your data with some changes and it seems to be working. Let if you know any issue on top of that, will try to fix it

use below command using your file-name

`cat file-name | sed  s/"rpc-whitelist-enabled: true"/"rpc-whitelist-enabled : false"/g`

if above works, use below command to update your input file. change file-name with your file-name

`sed -i s/"rpc-whitelist-enabled: true"/"rpc-whitelist-enabled : false"/g file-name`

Comment: which os are you using ? can you share exact error message , because I have tested it before sharing with you

Comment: If you have no erros, that means its working, but not matching what its trying to match. So using above command which start with cat, try to narrow down criteria,and check few times. You will know what exactly is not matching , and we will find the solution

Comment: Nop, because the value doesn't change

Comment: cat file-name | sed  's/\"rpc-whitelist-enabled\": true/\"rpc-whitelist-enabled\" : false/g'